# Print JSON string without quotes and brackets

Tags: javascript, json, object

How can I print a value of an object using JSON.stringify() without the curly brackets and quote marks.

For example when I do this:

```
var string = "this is a string";

var test = JSON.stringify(myJsonObject);

div.innerHTML = test;
```

the output is this:

```
{"vavlue":" this is a string"}
```

How can I output only the actual string without anything else?

i.e :

```
this is a string
```

Comment: div.innerHTML = test.value;

Comment: @iKnowKungFoo or `test.vavlue`, :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your JSON object looks like:

```
myJsonObject = {"vavlue":" this is a string"};
```

You don't need to stringify to get the string value, you can use this instead:

```
myJsonObject.value
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just

> div.innerHTML = myJsonObject.value;